# How To Obtain All the Nodes and Connections After Launching the GMF Project

Tags: eclipse-gmf

After launching the GMF project, I get a new window to make my own model.

After placing some nodes and connections, I should calculate according to their attributes. At first, HOW can I obtain all the information of every node and every connection?

Answer (score 1):

First , let's get the relevant editor:

```
DomainDiagramEditor d= (DomainDiagramEditor) PlatformUI.getWorkbench().getActiveWorkbenchWindow().getActivePage().getActiveEditor();
```

Now, you can either get all the editparts in your diagram , getting the relevant model from them:

```
final List children = d.getDiagramEditPart().getChildren();
```

gets you a list of EditParts.

Or, you can get the model objects directly with:

```
EObject element = d.getDiagram().getElement();
EList<EObject> eContents_ = element.eContents();
```

That gives you a list of all the model objects in the active editor.
Hope that answers your question